# Use this code and it works perfect, but when loading 48 rows [''] it breaks, does anyone know how to solve it?

Tags: python, mysql

```
from __future__ import print_function
import csv
import MySQLdb

print("Enter  File  To Be Export")
conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", port=3306, user="root", passwd="", db="database")
cursor = conn.cursor()
#sql = 'CREATE DATABASE test1'
sql ='''DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test1`; CREATE TABLE test1 (policyID int, statecode varchar(255), county varchar(255))'''
cursor.execute(sql)

with open('C:/Users/Desktop/Code/python/sample.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter = ',')
    for row in reader:
        print(row['policyID'], row['statecode'], row['county'])
        # insert
        conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", port=3306, user="root", passwd="", db="database")
        sql_statement = "INSERT INTO test1(policyID ,statecode,county) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)"
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.executemany(sql_statement,[(row['policyID'], row['statecode'], row['county'])])
        conn.escape_string(sql_statement)
        conn.commit()
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it breaks"?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):

Comment: with this same code can I enter a large csv? sorry I have no one else to turn to.

Comment: Please put the full traceback in the post so that we can help ;)

Comment: Put the traceback in the question, it probably won't fit/format into comments too nicely

Comment: won't let me paste the amount of characters

Comment: "Incorrect integer value: 'TELEFONO' for column 'TELEFONO' at row 1")

Comment: mysql.connection.query(self, query)
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (1366, "Inc
orrect integer value: 'TELEFONO' for colu
mn 'TELEFONO' at row 1")

Comment: line 253, in _do_
execute_many
    v = values % escape(next(args), conn)
TypeError: not all arguments converted during bytes formatti
ng

Comment: I managed to do it, but I could not install MySQLdb in pycarm, it is incredible but always a problem occurs